# Using classes in for loop in node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js

To be honest, I don't know what to ask for my case so I'll just add some details. I come from java so I am familiar with classes.

Let's take for instance a class and for making it easy, drop the private fields to public and no getter and setter

```
class User{
 public String name;
 public String email;
}
```

This is useful in certain cases, for instance have an array of users and then I can use something like:

```
for(User user: usersList){
   user.name='some new value'
   //since user is a class, code assist, suggests the name and also if I have user.namee it throws an error
}
```

Now moving into javascript, I can obtain an array and do something like

```
for (let user of usersList){
    user.name='some new value'
    //however if I type user.nammee no error is thrown and code assist does not know what to recomment
}
```

I think that now you may get the idea. I want it to make it easier to properly obtain the object fields with code assist and also avoid typing errors because of property name badly typed. Javascript classes from what I see have only methods... so what can I apply in this case?

Comment: You can have getter and setter methods in a class

Comment: A question about code assist really has more to do with your editor than with JavaScript.

Comment: I was pointing the class feature as it helped the code assist. The IDE is aware of the class properties so it can use it for validations...

Comment: Which IDE are you referring to?

Comment: If you like Java and static typing, look into TypeScript. Javascript is a scripting language, and doesn't provide this kind of stuff.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

JavaScript allows to reference properties which an object does not have: you can add them ad-hoc, and if you read non-existing properties, you just get `undefined`. This is how JavaScript works.

If you want to get an error when you try to assign to a non-existing property, then consider using the [`Object.seal`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/freeze) method, which you could apply in the constructor for your class:

```js
"use strict";
class User{
    constructor (name, email) {
        this.name = name;
        this.email = email;
        // Seal will disallow new properties
        Object.seal(this);
    }
}

const user = new User();

user.name = "Jeff";

console.log(user); // Shows property with "Jeff"

user.nammmeeee = "Jeff"; // Produces error
```

Make sure to use strict mode (`"use strict"`) as otherwise these errors are suppressed.

Answer (score 1):

check out [Typescript](//www.typescriptlang.org)

and [this "fiddle" on the TypeScript Playground](//www.typescriptlang.org/play/#src=%63%6c%61%73%73%20%55%73%65%72%20%7b%0a%09%63%6f%6e%73%74%72%75%63%74%6f%72%28%70%75%62%6c%69%63%20%6e%61%6d%65%3a%20%73%74%72%69%6e%67%2c%20%70%75%62%6c%69%63%20%65%6d%61%69%6c%3a%20%73%74%72%69%6e%67%20%3d%20%22%22%29%20%7b%20%7d%0a%0a%09%2f%2a%0a%09%70%75%62%6c%69%63%20%6e%61%6d%65%3a%20%73%74%72%69%6e%67%3b%0a%09%70%75%62%6c%69%63%20%65%6d%61%69%6c%3a%20%73%74%72%69%6e%67%3b%0a%0a%09%2f%2f%73%68%6f%72%74%68%61%6e%64%20%66%6f%72%0a%09%63%6f%6e%73%74%72%75%63%74%6f%72%28%6e%61%6d%65%3a%73%74%72%69%6e%67%2c%20%65%6d%61%69%6c%3a%73%74%72%69%6e%67%3d%22%22%29%20%7b%20%0a%09%09%74%68%69%73%2e%6e%61%6d%65%20%3d%20%6e%61%6d%65%3b%0a%09%09%74%68%69%73%2e%65%6d%61%69%6c%20%3d%20%65%6d%61%69%6c%3b%0a%09%7d%0a%09%2a%2f%0a%7d%0a%0a%76%61%72%20%75%73%65%72%73%4c%69%73%74%20%3d%20%5b%0a%09%6e%65%77%20%55%73%65%72%28%22%4a%61%63%6b%22%29%2c%0a%09%6e%65%77%20%55%73%65%72%28%22%4a%69%6c%6c%22%29%2c%0a%09%6e%65%77%20%55%73%65%72%28%22%4a%6f%65%22%29%0a%5d%3b%0a%0a%66%6f%72%20%28%6c%65%74%20%75%73%65%72%20%6f%66%20%75%73%65%72%73%4c%69%73%74%29%20%7b%20%0a%09%75%73%65%72%2e%65%6d%61%69%6c%20%3d%20%75%73%65%72%2e%6e%61%6d%65%20%2b%20%22%40%6d%61%69%6c%2e%63%6f%6d%22%3b%0a%7d)

```
class User {
    constructor(public name: string, public email: string = "") { }

    /*
    //shorthand for

    public name: string;
    public email: string;

    constructor(name:string, email:string="") { 
        this.name = name;
        this.email = email;
    }
    */
}

var usersList = [
    new User("Jack"),
    new User("Jill"),
    new User("Joe")
];

for (let user of usersList) { 
    user.email = user.name + "@mail.com";
}
```

and since `userList` is recognized as type `User[]`, `let user` is also typed as `let user:User`

Answer (score -2):

You can do this in javascript. Just that, your userslist will be array in which you will have your users. Loop will be for loop from 0 to length-1. This class will have some syntax like this.

var userclass = {
Name:'xyz',
Addr:'address',
.....other props
}

Comment: I think you misunderstood the question.